# No sound on Mac Mini running windows 10 Pro 64 bit

Tags: windows-10, mac, 64-bit

I have formatted my Mac Mini completely and re-install windows 10 Pro 64 bit on it instead. This means I am not running Parallels/boot camp or whatever its called. Only windows 10 Pro exists on this machine now.

Everything works fine except for sound, the strange thing is that I don't see any errors in the device manager for sound:

[image]

Of course I verified that my connection to my speakers work fine - if I put the mini-jack connected to the Mac Mini into my laptop it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you completely wiped it & installed Windows from scratch, then you are most definitely **not** "*running Parallels/boot camp or whatever its called*". What you have is a machine for which there are no drivers, nor can you get any... because you didn't use Boot Camp, which downloads & installs them as part of the setup. Your only 'fix' is to wipe it & start over, first get OS X back on it & then use Boot Camp [& that's assuming you have a mini on which Win10 is supported.]

Comment: Yes that is what I am in the process of now. Interestingly enough sounds works fine on the Mac Mini if I install Ubuntu, so it seems this is a windows specific issue. Will also try http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2016/03/12/installing-windows-10-on-a-mac-without-bootcamp/ since it seems boot camp is not that good.

Comment: Wish you luck with that lot ;-) tbh I've only ever done one Boot Camp install. I then migrated it to a separate disk & have carried it from Mac to Mac ever since. Never had an issue with it.

Comment: Hm wonder if its actually because it uses the HDMI sound since the mac mini is connected to my Samsung TV through a HDMI cable...

Comment: It's a possibility - but beyond my direct experience. I avoid HDMI because of it's 'television' heredity & rely on DVI or DisplayPort where I can.